# Equivalent of IsFilled="false" for PathFigure in Path Mini-language (Silverlight/WPF)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, path, pathgeometry

I'm trying to find the equivalent of [`IsFilled="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure.isfilled(v=VS.95).aspx) that is used in a PathGeometry, but for [Path Mini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=VS.95).aspx#abouthisdocument).

[image: left is Path Mini and right is PathGeometry]

You can see that the two paths below are identical, except for the one with geometries has `IsFilled="False"` in the second `<PathGeometry>.<PathGeometry.Figures>.<PathFigure>`. This is the desired behavior, but I'd like to have it for a Path Mini (i.e. in the first `<Path>`). I've looked through the documentation and can't seem to locate anything on it as it appears that Path Mini is not a collection of figures.

As I understand it, all shapes/geometries will get converted to path mini at run-time, so is there some way to reflect the compiled XAML to see how the interpreter renders the one with PathGeometry to Path Mini?

```
<Canvas Background="#FDB" Width="800" Height="600">

  <!-- this is the LEFT-HAND Path in the picture above -->
  <Path Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"
     Stroke="#385D8A" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="#4F81BD"
     Data="M0,0L102,0L102,102L0,102Z M46.15,49.01L-73.36,130.99L-96.42,-96.12L109.35,355.18">
  </Path>

  <!-- this is the RIGHT-HAND Path in the picture above -->
  <Path Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="100" Stroke="#385D8A" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="#4F81BD">
    <Path.Data>
      <GeometryGroup>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0" IsClosed="True">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="102,0" />
                <LineSegment Point="102,102" />
                <LineSegment Point="0,102" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
          </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure IsFilled="False" StartPoint="46.15,49.01">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="-73.36,130.99" />
                <LineSegment Point="-96.42,-96.12" />
                <LineSegment Point="109.35,355.18" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
          </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
      </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path mini-lanuage only supports outlines so strokes must be converted to fills.  This is straightforward to do yourself if you want one-pixel wide lines and you aren't too fussy about mitering or endcaps.  Just use skinny rectangles.  A true mathematical "grow" of an infinitely narrow stroke using the minimum number of points and handling crossings is quite a bit harder.  However you might be able to use the WPF rendering engine to do that for you since obviously it can already do it.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Accepting as it seems to be the only answer. Do you know of any documentation on path mini that is more detailed than the link I provided above?